# How do I overlay one raster over another

Tags: raster, postgis, postgresql, overlay, mapping

I have two rasters on a postgresql database one is a map of the world and the other looks like a weather map. I have been trying to figure out how to overlay one map on top of another.

What I have gotten so far is this

```
select 
ST_AsTIFF(
    ST_MapAlgebra(
        ST_ColorMap(
            ST_Resample(
                ST_Transform(
                    DM.rast, 3857
                ),
                DMB.rast
            ),
            '100% 255 0 0 255
            0% 0 0 0 0
            nv 0 0 0 0'
        ),
        ST_ColorMap(
            DMB.rast,
            '100% 255 255 255 255
            0% 0 0 0 0
            nv 0 0 0 0'
        ),
        '([rast2.val]+[rast1.val])/2'
    ),
'JPEG90')
from dailyMap DM
join dailymapbackground DMB on true;
```

However this does not produce a map where one is a background layer and the other is a front layer. I am uncertain on how I should go about this. I am very new to mapping and GIS functions. So I have just cobbled this together out of what I could learn from the docs.